# Support for Cg profiles in modern hardware

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia, cg

I have an inhouse application that uses the now deprecated nvidia scenix and Cg shaders.  It works fine, and as it is inhouse we can chose what hardware to run it on.

The shaders are currently using vp40/fp40 profiles (though I can change it to use later profiles like GLSLV/GLSLF).  I am trying to confirm that the current crop of nvidia hardware STILL supports Cg shaders?  i.e. if we purchase the latest OpenGL4 geforce or quadro cards, will they still support the Cg profiles?  I have asked on the nvidia forum but no answer.  Eventually we will have to upgrade to a new scene graph and GLSL, but I want to know what 'legacy' support there is for the Cg shaders.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're perfectly fine. In fact the GLSL implementation in the NVidia drivers is actually an add-on to the Cg compiler. even on latest generation GPUs the NVidia driver internally first translates GLSL to NV/ARB_programm_… assembly (source code in fact) and runs this through the assembler. It's unlikely NVidia is going to change that in the near future (although the introduction of SPIR-V may force their hand). And all the legacy OpenGL ARB/NV_program interfaces are supported just fine as extension (even to to OpenGL-4 core profile).